# How to create dynamic pdf cells in C# mvc

Tags: c#, itext

I have a view containing a table that has more than 30 columns which is changing with month i want to print it into pdf.But i need to create the pdf cell dynamically.ie if i select the month as august the pdf have 30 columns if i select february the pdf have 28 columns how can i do that anyone please help me.Below are the code.
[![table to be print as pdf][1]][1]

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 40f, 30f, 30f);
//     Document pdf = new Document(pageSize.A4,)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
 PdfPTable tablebody = new PdfPTable(pdfCell);
tablebody.TotalWidth = 500f;
 PdfPCell cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" Georoof \n\n MONTHLY FIELD VISIT REPORT", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, Font.BOLD)));
cell0.Colspan = 7;
cell0.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
cell0.PaddingBottom = 6f;
cell0.PaddingTop = 6f;
tablebody.AddCell(cell0);

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dealer", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD)));
cell1.Colspan = 1;
cell1.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
cell1.PaddingBottom = 6f;
cell1.PaddingTop = 6f;
tablebody.AddCell(cell1);

PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Executive", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD)));
cell2.Colspan = 1;
cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
cell2.PaddingBottom = 6f;
cell2.PaddingTop = 6f;
tablebody.AddCell(cell2);

PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Days", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD)));
cell3.Colspan = 1;
cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
cell3.PaddingBottom = 6f;
cell3.PaddingTop = 6f;
tablebody.AddCell(cell3);

for (int i = 4, j = 4; i <= DaysInMonth; i++)
{
    string cells = i.ToString();
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cells, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.BOLD)));

    cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    cell3.PaddingBottom = 6f;
    cell3.PaddingTop = 6f;
    tablebody.AddCell(cell3);
    j++;
}
```

Comment: [use code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to display your code instead of img

Comment: thanks i am new in this